# Resetting animation to adjusted position after Timer has expired

Tags: java, animation, timer, keylistener, paintcomponent

I am recreating the game space invaders and have reached the point of firing a projectile. I've been using the KeyListener class successfully so that when the spacebar is pressed my projectile fires. The issue is that it only updates it's position after it has been fired, so it fires from the position that laser canon was last placed not its current position.

My laserCanon class

```
/*
*The properties and behaviors of the laser canon
*/
package spaceinvaders;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class LaserCanon extends GameObject{
private int pnlWidth;//GamePanel width
private int pnlHeight;//GamePanel height
private final int moveInc = 15;//number of pixels moved when when arrow key   is pressed

//Constructor
public LaserCanon(int pnlWidth, int pnlHeight){
    super();
    this.pnlWidth = pnlWidth;
    this.pnlHeight = pnlHeight;
    getLocation().x=pnlWidth;//sets initial location of canon
    getLocation().y=pnlHeight;//sets intial location of canon
    setColor(Color.green);//canon is green
    setVisible(true);
}
public LaserCanon(){
    super();
}

//draws laser canon using GamePanel height and width
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(this.getColor());
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon();//canon is in shape of triangle
    triangle.addPoint(getLocation().x, getLocation().y);//bottom right point
    triangle.addPoint(getLocation().x-100, getLocation().y);//bottom right point
    triangle.addPoint(getLocation().x-50, getLocation().y-75);//top point
    g.fillPolygon(triangle);
}

//returns each property in a string
@Override
public String toString(){
    String string = super.toString();
    string = getPnlWidth() + "|" + getPnlHeight() + "|" + getMoveInc();
    return string;
}

//moves canon left
public void moveLeft(){
    if(getLocation().getX()>50){
        System.out.println("Left key pressed\n" + getLocation().getX());
        getLocation().x-=moveInc;
    }    
}
//moves canon right
public void moveRight(){
    if(getLocation().getX()<pnlWidth){
        System.out.println("Right key pressed\n" + getLocation().getX());
        getLocation().x+=moveInc;
    }    
}
//accessor and mutator methods
```

My Projectile Class

```
public class Projectile extends GameObject{
private int speed;//speed at which the projectile moves
private int locX;
private int locY;
private GamePanel gamePanel;

//constructor
public Projectile(int speed, GamePanel gp){
    super();
    this.speed = speed;
    gamePanel = gp;
    //sets location of projectile to same location as canon Starting at top point
    this.locX = gamePanel.getLaserCanon().getLocation().x-50;
    this.locY = gamePanel.getLaserCanon().getLocation().y-75;
    setColor(Color.cyan);//projectile is cyan
    setVisible(false);//not visible to start
}
public Projectile(){
    super();
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
    if(isVisible())
        g.setColor(this.getColor());
    else
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    Polygon triangle1 = new Polygon();
    triangle1.addPoint(getLocX()-5, getLocY());//bottom left point
    triangle1.addPoint(getLocX()+5, getLocY());//bottom right point
    triangle1.addPoint(getLocX(), getLocY()-15);//top middle point
    Polygon triangle2 = new Polygon();
    triangle2.addPoint(getLocX(), getLocY()+3);//bottom middle point
    triangle2.addPoint(getLocX()-5, getLocY()-10);//bottom left point
    triangle2.addPoint(getLocX()+5, getLocY()-10);//bottom right point
    g.fillPolygon(triangle1);
    g.fillPolygon(triangle2);
}

public int move(){
    setLocY(getLocY() - getSpeed());
    return getLocY();    
}
//accessor and mutators
```

And my game panel class to hold each of the former:

```
package spaceinvaders;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{();
private LaserCanon laserCanon;
private Projectile projectile;

private Timer projectileTimer;//used to animate the projectile fired from LaserCanon

//constructor
public GamePanel(){
    setSize(800,800);//size of panel
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);//background
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 3));//border

    laserCanon = new LaserCanon(getWidth(), getHeight());

    projectile = new Projectile(20,this);
    projectileTimer = new Timer(50, new TimerListener());
    //instantiate other GameObjects

    //gives focus to this panel for KeyListener
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocus();
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k){
    int key = k.getKeyCode();
    if(key == k.VK_LEFT){//if left arrow is pressed
        getLaserCanon().moveLeft();
        repaint();
    }
    else if(key == k.VK_RIGHT){//if right arrow is pressed
        getLaserCanon().moveRight();
        repaint();
    }
    else if(key == k.VK_SPACE){
       System.out.println("fired!");
        getProjectile().setVisible(true);
        getProjectileTimer().start();
   }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k){
    //dummy method
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k){
   //dummy method

}
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(getProjectile().move()>-15){
            repaint();
        }    
        else{
            getProjectileTimer().stop();
            getProjectile().setVisible(false);
            projectile.setLocX(laserCanon.getLocation().x-50);
            projectile.setLocY(laserCanon.getLocation().y-75);
            repaint();
        }
    }
} 
//used to call draw methods
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    getLaserCanon().draw(g);
    getProjectile().draw(g);
}
```

After placing

```
projectile.setLocX(laserCanon.getLocation().x-50);
projectile.setLocY(laserCanon.getLocation().y-75);
```

in my TimerListener class after it has detected that the projectile is no longer on screen I realized that I need another set of these methods somewhere else and have been playing around with it, but I can't seem to figure out where. Anywhere else I place them solves the position problem, but I lose the animation. 
Basically, where ever my laser canon goes I need my projectile to follow and fire from the laser canon's position. How can I get that to happen?

Side note: There is an abstract class GameObject that holds the visibility, location (using the Point class), and color of my projectile and laser canon.

Comment: 1) [M-V-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: How is the position of the projectile first set when the cannon is fired?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The projectile is set to placed at the initial position of the canon. So even if I move the canon before firing it for the first time, the projectile fires from the initial position

Answer (score 0):

I found that by adding in a moveLeft() and moveRight() methods like those that are in my LaserCanon class, to my projectile class it would move with the canon rather than depending on the cannon to move.